# npm module n emits errors

Tags: npm, n

After installing n by command 'sudo npm install -g n',
I want list all node versions,but some errors come out, even though, n can work normally!
As bellow:

```
$ n list
/usr/bin/n: line 262: which: command not found
/usr/bin/n: line 262: which: command not found

0.0.1
0.0.2
0.0.3
0.0.4
```

I don't know why, there is no need to configure my bin foldeer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it, after npm install which...

```
sudo npm install -g whitch
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing which

```
sudo apt-get install which
```

Comment: thx,  my linux has installed which, I find that, my npm didn't install which, so I npm install which again, then I solved it....

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the current version of `n`.

Old versions of `n` used the `which` command which is not standard. Newer versions only use `command -v` which is a standard posix command.